# How to design database table for working hours?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hei guys, I'm trying to help my friend to design database tables. It is for a system tracking workers' working hours in a factory by reading card info from certain card readers. Each time a worker log his in/out information, there would be an record saved.

My problem is, how can I calculate each worker's working time (in minutes), each workday? A worker may work from 8:00AM~20:00PM, or 20:00PM~8:00AM.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

---

You guys did give me a lot of help. 
The previous design is a table with in-record or out-record. It was hard for me to locate which ones belong to the same work-time-span. I now use another table with records both have the in-time and out-time in the same record. Insert to save in-time, update to save out-time, which makes it easy to calculate the total minutes between in-time and out-time.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What if midnight is in between the current working session? Do the whole working hours are counting for the day the worker began or for the day he ended working or do you have to split it by midnight?

Comment: What about daylight saving time switch while you're working? What is in fact saved when a worker logs in and out? Just date and time?

Comment: @Fatal when dealing with dates and times it's always good to only use UTC Values.

Comment: @balexandre I agree, but you've to be aware.

Comment: Yeah. If a worker works at night. I have to calculate his working time from the time he came to work to the time he left for home, which is a big trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT datediff(hh,'2011-08-30 04:47','2011-08-30 05:48') as [Hour(s) Worked]
Hour(s) Worked
--------------
1
```

Comment: datediff(mi, ...) will calculate minutes

Comment: `DATEDIFF(hh,...)` will give you strange results. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 2):

a simple example with 2 tables

```
[TblUsers]
User_id        PK
FirstName
LastName

[TblSchedule]
Schedule_id    PK
User_id        FK
Date_From
Date_To
```

to get a daily work grid with times, you can write something like:

```
SELECT 
  u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName as [username],
  CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@datetime as float)) as datetime) as [date],
  DATEDIFF(minute, s.Date_To, s.Date_From) as [workMinutes]
FROM 
  [TblSchedule] s, [TblUsers] u
WHERE
 s.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY 
  u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName,
  CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@datetime as float)) as datetime)
ORDER BY 
 s.Date_From;
```

Comment: I just can't with the table names, I'm sorry. Please consider `User` (or `SystemUser` to avoid keyword conflict) and `Schedule` instead of using prefixes.

Comment: He has a table with `IN-Record` and `OUT-Records`. Furthermore I am sure it must be prepared for multiple Check-In and Check-Out a day, i.e. workers are checking-out for lunch and afterwards they check-in again.

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate the Minutes between each `IN-Record` and the following `OUT-Record` from this worker. If you want it for a whole day then fetch the relevant records and sum up the relevant differences.

The more complex thing here is when some worker forget about stamping. Your program have to be   prepared for such cases.

Also be aware of things like daylight saving time. Time-Calcs can be very complicated.

I think I would do calculation on application level and not in SQL in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEDIFF` can give you some strange results. 
For example take this two `DATETIME2` (I presume you have SQL Server 2008) values that have a difference of 5 minutes:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh,'2011-01-01 04:59:00','2011-01-01 05:04:00') 
Results
-----------
1
```

The result is *somehow* strange: 1 hour. Strange, because the difference in minutes is 5 minutes but the difference in hours is 1 hour and we know that 1 hour = 60 minutse. Please read this [article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/datediff-function-demystified) to see the explanations.

Solutions:

1) Instead of `DATEDIFF(hh,...)` use `DATEDIFF(mi,...)` 
Ex:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi,'2011-01-01 07:55:00','2011-01-01 16:02:00') [Minutes]
    ,DATEDIFF(mi,'2011-01-01 07:55:00','2011-01-01 16:02:00')/60 [Hours] 
    --8 hours
    ,DATEDIFF(mi,'2011-01-01 07:55:00','2011-01-01 16:02:00')%60 [Additional minute] 
    --7 minute
```

But:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi,'2011-01-01 08:00:59','2011-01-01 16:00:05') [Minutes] 
        --480
        ,DATEDIFF(ss,'2011-01-01 08:00:59','2011-01-01 16:00:05')/60 [Seconds/60] 
        --479
```

2) Instead of using `DATEDIFF` function (with `DATETIME[2][OFFSET]` data types) use `DATETIME` values with the - operator:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    TestId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Enter] DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,[Exit] DATETIME NOT NULL
);
INSERT  @Test
VALUES  ('2011-01-01 07:55:00','2011-01-01 16:02:02')
        ,('2011-01-01 08:00:59','2011-01-01 16:00:05');

SELECT  *
        ,t.[Exit] - t.[Enter] AS MyDateDiff
        ,DATEPART(hh,t.[Exit] - t.[Enter]) [Hours]
        ,DATEPART(mi,t.[Exit] - t.[Enter]) [Additional minutes]
        ,DATEPART(ss,t.[Exit] - t.[Enter]) [Additional seconds]
FROM    @Test t
```

Results:

```
TestId      Enter                   Exit                    MyDateDiff              Hours       Additional minute Additional seconds
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------------- ------------------
1           2011-01-01 07:55:00.000 2011-01-01 16:02:02.000 1900-01-01 08:07:02.000 8           7                 2
2           2011-01-01 08:00:59.000 2011-01-01 16:00:05.000 1900-01-01 07:59:06.000 7           59                6
```